# Unable to uncheck image checkbox using qtp

Tags: qtp

I have a webtable which has a column of image checkboxes, one for each row. They are all checked and I want to uncheck them. I have pasted the properties of one of the image checkbox below
Class Name = Image, abs_x=275, abs_y=374, alt=Checked, class=, file name=ig_checkbox_on.gif, html id=x:593231214.20:chkState:1, html tag:=IMG,
image type:=Plain Image, name=Image, outerhtml=, src=http://qaapp2/ig_res/Default/images/ig_checkbox_on.gif, visible=True

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ChildObjects` on the `WebTable` to return all the objects with `file name` = *ig_checkbox_on.gif* and then iterate them and click each.

Comment: Hi Motti,  I added the following line of code to the script but is erroring out  Set oDesc = Description.Create
oDesc("file name").Value = "ig_checkbox_on.gif"
'oDesc("alt").Value = "Checked"
Set images = oBrowser.WebTable("html id:=x:593231214.4:mkr:dataTbl.hdn").ChildObjects(oDesc)


msgbox images.count

For i = 1 to images.count
 images(i).click
    msgbox Err.Number
Next

Comment: also I put this line right on top of it all  set oBrowser = Browser("Browser").Window("Fax Window").Page("Untitled Page")

Comment: Nevermind, I found a solution for clicking  just added the line  Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2 before the click